# OpenGL ES 2.0 Translation for Android- seems to mess up matrices

Tags: android, opengl-es, matrix, opengl-es-2.0, translate

I'm trying to translate a triangle strip. My program gets the position of the person's finger touch and creates a box there. I have trouble applying translation, the shape is created on every touch at the same place and than translated to the postion of touch by way of Matrix.translateM. When I do this, I everything goes screwy! the boxes are stretched thinly from an edge of the screen to the center, getting infinitely smaller. Atleast it is registering the touch. Maybe it doesn't work because MotionEvent getX and y and not normalized? but I don't see how this would mess up the mvp Matrix.

Basically its like this onDrawFrame:

For each shape
 set up attribute pointers
 translate MMatrix
 multiply MM, VM store in mvp
 multiply MVP, Proj
 draw

I know the view and proj matrices work because if I disable the translation it works fine.

As expected, it translates on every frame more and more- I had the translation done in the constructor of shape but for the sake of simplicity put it here and tested it, same weird result

Comment: Did you ever figure out what's causing this? I'm seeing a weird deformation on my geometry when translating it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard with only that tiny piece of psuedo-code, but I'll try anyways;
First make sure you have called Matrix.setIdentity() on your modelMatrix, second, make sure it isn't your camera that has a weird perspective causing the "infinite stretch".